# Magento 2 Object of class could not be converted to string

Tags: magento2

```
Error: Object of class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\Interceptor could not be converted to string in Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:78
```

What does this error means ?

```
if ($amount) {
    $amount = $this->priceCurrency->roundPrice($amount);
    $creditmemo->setBsCustomerBalTotalRefunded($amount);
    $creditmemo->setCustomerBalTotalRefunded($amount);
    **$creditmemo->setCustomerBalanceRefundFlag(true);** // line 79
    if (!empty($tracking_info)) {
        $tracking_info_comment = implode("\n", $tracking_info);
        $creditmemo->addComment($tracking_info_comment);
    }
    $creditmemo = $this->creditmemoRepository->save($creditmemo);
    $this->registry->unregister('current_creditmemo');
    $this->creditmemoSender->send($creditmemo);
    $result[0] = true;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: sorry, but which one is line number 78 in this code ?

Comment: I have updated question, please share your thoughts

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: The above code which you mentioned is from which php file.. please tell the filepath and filename also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In escaper.php file, Here your code stucks at line no. 78 
[image]

So in your code, try to find the type of variables using the function.

```
$a=$amount;<br>
echo gettype($a);
```

Also, you need to go inside the body of these functions to see what they accept as parameter and what is their return type.

```
echo gettype($amount);  // to check the type.
    $amount = $this->priceCurrency->roundPrice($amount);
echo gettype($amount); //after conversion type
    $creditmemo->setBsCustomerBalTotalRefunded($amount);//go inside the body of 
                                                         //these functions where 
    $creditmemo->setCustomerBalTotalRefunded($amount);//these two functions 
                                                        //written.
```

Also Backtrace $creditmemo to check more deeply(may be here - Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\Interceptor ), the problem you are facing is because of type conversion only. 
 Try something like convert it to

```
$creditmemo->setCustomerBalanceRefundFlag(1);
```

As per error you are trying to convert an object to string, we need to find where exactly this is happening and also we need to get extract the string from that object then we should use it.

Comment: Thanks Vibhore Jain, i am checking it by printing their type. (above variables)

Comment: Hello Vibhore, i am not able to find "setBsCustomerBalTotalRefunded" as these are magic method. how should i check these methods to look at its acceptable arg type & return type.
please advise me on this

Comment: I have logged before & after amount type & its all "double" in type.

Comment: from your app root folder - /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Creditmemo.php check this file and you shown only one error line.. i think some more lines must be there.. or may you share the screenshot of the error.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer.
I have found there was error in above lines.
where type conversion has been made. i have fixed it.
Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I am not sure why the error line was wrong.
error was on other line but it shows some other line number.